# How to group objects by id returned by mnesia:match_object function

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I need to group mnesia records by sender_id, here is the record:

```
-record(pm,{sender_id, recipient_id, msg, time}).
```

basically I need to fetch all records where `recipient_id=X` and group them by `sender_id`

what is the fastest way to do it?

Situation is obvious and clear I think.

Comment: What version of Erlang are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to solve this.

**Get the results and sort them by sender_id**

This is by far the simplest solution. Just get result (a list of records) as you normally would and [sort the records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723064/sorting-erlang-records-in-a-list) by sender_id:

```
lists:sort(fun(A, B) ->
    A#pm.sender_id < B#pm.sender_id
end, Results).
```

**Use qlc:fold/3**

This is a bit more involved, but it does seem a little more elegant the using a plain old `lists:sort/2`. Instead of returning a list it returns a dict.

```
select_grouped_pms_for_recipient(RecipientId) ->
    Q = qlc:q([E || E <- mnesia:table(pm), E#pm.recipient_id == RecipientId]),
    qlc:fold(fun group/2, dict:new(), Q).

group(Record, Acc) ->
    dict:append(Record#pm.sender_id, Record, Acc).
```

In the `group/2` function we push the record onto a list of values for sender ID in the `dict` accumulator. The `select_grouped_pms_for_recipient/1` will return the resulting `dict` containing lists of all the records grouped under the sender ID keys.

The Erlang mailing list has is a treasure trove of good questions and answers. I found [this question](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-November/031249.html) on the mailing list, which is very similar to your question.

**Which is faster?**

Looking at these solutions I'm not sure there will be a big difference in performance. I imagine they are about the same, but with the qlc the lock is held during all the grouping logic is executed for each item received, so it may hold the Mnesia lock for a bit longer.